# programmatically send money in native app BUT with delay

Tags: ios, paypal, e-commerce

Here's the use case I'm trying to support:

I have three native app users A, B and C.  On day one, Users A and B manually make a commitment to send user C $20 seven days from day one based on the successful completion of an action by user C.  The app retains the logic to determine if user C has completed the action and if so, programmatically sends payment to user C on behalf of users A and B on day seven.

1) Is the above supported by Paypal? (assuming the transaction is completed at the service layer, not the app layer)

I've researched this https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-batch-or-single-payout but it seems like this is geared toward a **one to many** relationship between a merchant and multiple payees.

What I need to support is a **many to many** relationship between users who aren't merchants like this https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/send-money-online

2) If not, are there alternate providers who can support the above?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a server based app with iOS clients. The clients make a commitment to the server, when the action is completed the server is sent that information and it dispenses the cash to the recipient.

Comment: Agreed.  Seems like I could be able to pull this off with the Adaptive Payment API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/